# SSDT Publish Timeout

Tags: sql, deployment, timeout, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I usually deploy using the SQLPackage command prompt route but this time when I try to release to the Test server it times out.

I had tried to set the Timeout property in the registry as per the blog post but it does not help either..

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2014/11/13/timeout-expired-while-publishing-to-sql-database-via-ssdt/

When I try to investigate what part of the publish is causing the delay I could identify this. This query keep running for a long time resulting in the timeout during the publish. I ran the same in Dev and production and it runs instantly and returns zero rows as we do not have any spatial indexes in the system..

I tried to simplify the query and when I run the below it runs immediately and returns an empty result set as expected.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    [sys].[spatial_indexes]          AS [si] WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [sys].[objects]       AS [o] WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON [si].[object_id] =         [o].[object_id] INNER JOIN [sys].[spatial_index_tessellations] [sit] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [sit].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [sit].[index_id]
WHERE [si].[is_hypothetical] = 0
```

But when I add the where clause with it keeps running for a long time.. Can you help me out what could be wrong here and any possible fixes I could try to resolve this?

AND OBJECTPROPERTY([o].[object_id], N'IsSystemTable') = 0

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    [sys].[spatial_indexes]          AS [si] WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [sys].[objects]       AS [o] WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON [si].[object_id] =         [o].[object_id] INNER JOIN [sys].[spatial_index_tessellations] [sit] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [sit].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [sit].[index_id]
WHERE [si].[is_hypothetical] = 0
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY([o].[object_id], N'IsSystemTable') = 0
```

Henrik added the estimated execution plan from SQL Sentry Plan Explorer:
[image]

Comment: I work with Senthil, and can add that the Estimated Cost of the last query is only 108. It should be over in seconds. There is no blocking.

Comment: The query runs fine on our development server, and our production server. It is the test server that is acting up.

Comment: Query plans at https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/3530/tfs-runs-this-query-when-deploying.html

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I ran into the same problem as you this week after we turned on TF4199 in SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU6. Suddenly our builds for some databases were timing out, others were fine.  We thought it was due to the size of the dacpac however our largest DB was not affected.  We did try updating the statistics, they did not work for us.  The SQLPackage.exe error we were getting was:

```
*** Error extracting database:Could not extract package from specified database.

Unable to reconnect to database: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The wait operation timed out
```

So I took what you had for a query and did some investigating.  Using SQL Sentry I found that the join diagram looks like this: [image: Join Diagram]

I created the script below (read a bit further) to see if I could update the statics on the tables (your thought process so thank you).  What I found was that once you update the stats on the following:

```
sys.sysschobjs
sys.sysobjvalues
sys.sysidxstats
sys.syssingleobjrefs
```

the query that you have shown above went from 51m 15s (yes, it took that long) to 0s.  Here is the code I used to fix my problem of updating the statics for the above objects (we had multiple DB with the problem):

```
exec sp_msforeachdb '        
use [?];
update statistics sys.sysschobjs;
update statistics sys.sysobjvalues;
update statistics sys.sysidxstats;
update statistics sys.syssingleobjrefs;
';
```

I hope this helps, the problem you are running into is that the statics on those four tables are out of date and need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since running DBCC CHECKDB will take so long to complete on the said DataWarehouse database, I ran DBCC CHECKALLOC and DBCC CHECKCATALOG instead and did not see any issues.

After the index statistics were updated on the target database the query now runs in seconds.